# Amazon SNS not sending sms after account creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

I tried sending sms with amazon sns and I got

SMS message published to phone number +23481XXXXXXX successfully.
Message "ID": *********************

But the message status show "fail".

Please is there any other thing I have to do after verifying my account before I start sending sms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also want to check if the region you're using supports sms and if the country you're trying to send has support.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-supported-regions-countries.html

Not sure if this is just SNS related or if you're trying to send sms after an account was created in cognito, might want to check region support for that too

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-email-phone-verification.html

Answer (score 0):

You can activate **Delivery status logging** to obtain a more-detailed log for SMS messages.

From [Viewing Amazon CloudWatch metrics and logs for SMS deliveries - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html):

- Activate Delivery status logging
- Send a message
- View the results in Amazon CloudWatch Logs

Here is an example log entry:

```json
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "1077257a-92f3-5ca3-bc97-6a915b310625",
        "timestamp": "2016-06-28 00:40:34.559"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "mnc": 0,
        "destination": "+1XXX5550100",
        "priceInUSD": 0.00645,
        "smsType": "Transactional",
        "mcc": 0,
        "providerResponse": "Unknown error attempting to reach phone",
        "dwellTimeMs": 1420,
        "dwellTimeMsUntilDeviceAck": 1692
    },
    "status": "FAILURE"
}
```